# Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric. when calling function inside procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

Here is my procedure created in SQL Server 2016.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_getProductInfo] 
    @CompanyId VARCHAR(50) = '',
    @ProductIds VARCHAR(max) = '',
    @IsChange VARCHAR(100) = '0',
    @PaymentOptionId VARCHAR(100) = '0',
    @MetalTypeId VARCHAR(100) = '0',
    @MetalGradeId VARCHAR(100) = '0',
    @FullCutClarityId_P1 VARCHAR(100) = '0',
    @SingleCutClarityId_P1 VARCHAR(100) = '0',
    @IsconvertedToFullCut_P1 VARCHAR(100) = '0',
    @FullCutClarityId_P2 VARCHAR(100) = '0',
    @SingleCutClarityId_P2 VARCHAR(100) = '0',
    @IsconvertedToFullCut_P2 VARCHAR(100) = '0'
AS
    DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(8000) = ''
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON  
    SET @SQL = 'SELECT dbo.Product.Id, dbo.Product.ItemSku, dbo.Product.ProductName, dbo.Product.ParentSku, dbo.Product.Quantity,
                       (SELECT TotalProductPrice FROM dbo.fn_returnChangedB2BCost(dbo.Product.Id,'+@CompanyId+','+@IsChange+','+@PaymentOptionId+','+@MetalTypeId+','+@MetalGradeId+','+@FullCutClarityId_P1+','+@SingleCutClarityId_P1+','+@IsconvertedToFullCut_P1+','+@FullCutClarityId_P2+','+@SingleCutClarityId_P2+','+@IsconvertedToFullCut_P2+')) AS StandardPrice, dbo.Product.SalePrice
                FROM dbo.Product 
                WHERE dbo.Product.CompanyId = '+@CompanyId+' AND dbo.Product.Id in(' + @ProductIds +')'

    EXEC (@SQL)
END
```

and the function is

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_returnChangedB2BCost] 
    (@ProductId BIGINT = 0,
     @CompanyId INT = 0,
     @IsChangeByCritariya BIT = 0,
     @PaymentOptionId INT = 0,
     @MetalTypeId BIGINT = 0,
     @MetalGradeId BIGINT = 0,
     @FullCutClarityId_P1 BIGINT = 0,
     @SingleCutClarityId_P1 BIGINT = 0,
     @IsConvertedToFullCut_P1 BIT = 0,
     @FullCutClarityId_P2 BIGINT = 0,
     @SingleCutClarityId_P2 BIGINT = 0,
     @IsConvertedToFullCut_P2 BIT = 0)
RETURNS @ReturnTable TABLE (TotalProductPrice DECIMAL(18, 4))
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @ReturnTable (TotalProductPrice) 
        SELECT 120
    RETURN 
END
```

Now my problem is when i call the procedure it returns a error that is ..

> Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric.

But instead of puting "dbo.Product.Id" in the functiuon, when i pass direct product id like ..

```
(SELECT TotalProductPrice FROM dbo.fn_returnChangedB2BCost(3596,'+@CompanyId+','+@IsChange+','+@PaymentOptionId+','+@MetalTypeId+','+@MetalGradeId+','+@FullCutClarityId_P1+','+@SingleCutClarityId_P1+','+@IsconvertedToFullCut_P1+','+@FullCutClarityId_P2+','+@SingleCutClarityId_P2+','+@IsconvertedToFullCut_P2+')) as StandardPrice
```

Then it works fine.

I can't find the solution. Please help.

Thank you

Comment: This is wide open to sql injection. It needs to be rewritten without dynamic sql. And what is the point of that function? It does nothing but return a hard coded value? It also receives a mountain of parameters that it just throws away. Might want to take a peek here also. https://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix

Comment: Why are all the parameters, that are `int` or `bigint` in the function `varchar(100)` in the procedure?

Comment: @SeanLange  the function return a Price value. the function have lots of steps , I was not mentioned those steps are here . when i call the function separately, it's works fine, but when i call it through procedure using dynamic sql, it's throw the error.

Comment: @stickybit No problem with int or bigint . because when i use only Id that is 3596, it does not return any error

Comment: `EXEC [dbo].[sp_getProductInfo] 'bananas', 'bananas', 'bananas', 'bananas', 'bananas', 'bananas', 'bananas', 'bananas', 'bananas', 'bananas', 'bananas', 'bananas';` and you have a problem...

Comment: Take the excellent answer from Gordon as a great start. Then to handle the list of ProductIDs you should consider using a table valued parameter. If you do that you don't need dynamic sql anymore.

Comment: Side note: you should **not** use the `sp_` prefix for your stored procedures. Microsoft has [reserved that prefix for its own use (see *Naming Stored Procedures*)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190669%28v=sql.105%29.aspx), and you do run the risk of a name clash sometime in the future. [It's also bad for your stored procedure performance](http://www.sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix). It's best to just simply avoid `sp_` and use something else as a prefix - or no prefix at all!

Answer (score 1):

I suspect your problem is here:

```
set @SQL='SELECT        dbo.Product.Id, dbo.Product.ItemSku, dbo.Product.ProductName, dbo.Product.ParentSku, dbo.Product.Quantity,
(select TotalProductPrice from dbo.fn_returnChangedB2BCost(dbo.Product.Id,'+@CompanyId+','+@IsChange+','+@PaymentOptionId+','+@MetalTypeId+','+@MetalGradeId+','+@FullCutClarityId_P1+','+@SingleCutClarityId_P1+','+@IsconvertedToFullCut_P1+','+@FullCutClarityId_P2+','+@SingleCutClarityId_P2+','+@IsconvertedToFullCut_P2+')) as StandardPrice, dbo.Product.SalePrice
        FROM            dbo.Product 
         where dbo.Product.CompanyId='+@CompanyId+' and dbo.Product.Id in(' + @ProductIds +')'

exec (@SQL)
```

You should pass data in as parameters -- when possible.  The `@ProductIds` are a bit tricky, so a good start is:

```
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = '';

set @SQL = N'
SELECT p.Id, p.ItemSku, p.ProductName, p.ParentSku, p.Quantity,
       (select TotalProductPrice
FROM dbo.fn_returnChangedB2BCost(p.Id, @CompanyId, @IsChange, @PaymentOptionId, @MetalTypeId, @MetalGradeId, @FullCutClarityId_P1, @SingleCutClarityId_P1, @IsconvertedToFullCut_P1, @FullCutClarityId_P2, @SingleCutClarityId_P2, @IsconvertedToFullCut_P2)
                                ) as StandardPrice,
       p.SalePrice
FROM dbo.Product 
WHERE dbo.Product.CompanyId =@CompanyId and p.Id in(' + @ProductIds +')';

exec sp_executesql @sql,
                   N'@ProductId bigint, @CompanyId, @IsChangeByCritariya, @PaymentOptionId, @MetalTypeId, @MetalGradeId, @FullCutClarityId_P1, @SingleCutClarityId_P1, @IsConvertedToFullCut_P1, @FullCutClarityId_P2, @SingleCutClarityId_P2, @IsConvertedToFullCut_P2',
                   @ProductId=@ProductId,
                   @CompanyId=@CompanyId ,
                   @IsChangeByCritariya=@IsChangeByCritariya,
                   @PaymentOptionId=@PaymentOptionId,
                   @MetalTypeId=@MetalTypeId,
                   @MetalGradeId=@MetalGradeId,
                   @FullCutClarityId_P1=@FullCutClarityId_P1,
                   @SingleCutClarityId_P1=@SingleCutClarityId_P1,
                   @IsConvertedToFullCut_P1=@IsConvertedToFullCut_P1,
                   @FullCutClarityId_P2=@FullCutClarityId_P2,
                   @SingleCutClarityId_P2=@SingleCutClarityId_P2,
                   @IsConvertedToFullCut_P2=@IsConvertedToFullCut_P2;
```

Comment: I would say to use a table valued parameter instead of the list of ProductIDs. Then this would no longer be susceptible to sql injection because you wouldn't need dynamic sql anymore at all.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff thank you for your suggestion. But Now after use the above code i face a new problem that is "Procedure expects parameter '@statement' of type 'ntext/nchar/nvarchar'." because i use "varchar" everywhere . If i use "nvarchar(max)", it exceed the max length and throw another error. that's why i use " varchar" and run through "exec (@sql)".

Comment: @AbhijitDas . . . `@SQL` needs to be `NVARCHAR()`.  Procedures can handle  any of the string types.

Answer (score 0):

In your query, condition in Where clause with dbo.Product.Id in(' + @ProductIds +')'. Please check is there any extra ',' at the end of the string.
I suggest to use below function to make list(Rows) from comma separated string.

```
DECLARE @input_xml XML

SELECT @input_xml = Cast('<root><x>'+ Replace(@ProductIds, ',', '</x><x>')+ '</x></root>' AS XML)

SELECT f.x.value('.', 'BIGINT') AS ProductId
INTO #list_to_table
FROM @input_xml.nodes('/root/x') f(x)
```

Now, make a join of this temp table with your Query, and this one is the simple query so avoid use of Dynamic SQL.